# Lambda times out while accessing S3 Bucket in another account using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to access S3 bucket in another account from my AWS Lambda using boto3. Below are the steps I configured.:
1. In Account A where my Lambda is I create Execution role (Lambda-S3-SNS-VPC-Role) and attach to it one AmazonS3FullAccess Managed Policy and one Inline policy as:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1489133353000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<Account-B-ID>:role/access-s3-bucket-from-lambda-in-another-acc-role"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In Account-B, where my S3 bucket is present, I created one IAM Role (access-s3-bucket-from-lambda-in-another-acc-role) as below:
- Attached AmazonS3FullAccess  managed policy and in Trust Relationship :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-A-ID>:role/Lambda-S3-SNS-VPC-Role",
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, in S3 Bucket in account B, gave below bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-A-ID>:role/Lambda-S3-SNS-VPC-Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-in-acc-B",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-in-acc-B/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my Lambda Function code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')

    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::<Account-B-ID>:role/access-s3-bucket-from-lambda-in-another-acc-role",
        RoleSessionName="cross_acct_lambda"
    )
    print('acct_b: ',acct_b)
```

But while testing, nothing is happening and the Function gets timed out. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your function is timing-out, but I'd like to recommend a different approach:

- Lambda function in `Account-A` that runs with IAM Role `Lambda-S3-SNS-VPC-Role`
- `Bucket-B` in `Account-B` with a Bucket policy that permits access from `Lambda-S3-SNS-VPC-Role` (this is exactly as you have shown above)

That's all you need!

There is **no need to assume an IAM Role** from `Account-B` because the Bucket Policy on `Bucket-B` is permitting the access from the IAM Role used by the Lambda function.

Comment: I got it worked by moving my Lambda Outside VPC. I don't know why its not working within VPC though I already have SNS VPC Endpoint created. I removed the Inline Policy from my Lambda Execution role now and got the Lambda working as well but outside VPC. Any thing which I need to configure more to make it work within VPC?

Comment: If an AWS Lambda function is connected to a VPC, it can only obtain Internet access if: (a) it is connected to a private subnet and (b) there is a NAT Gateway in a public subnet, and the private subnet Route Tables are pointing to the NAT Gateway.

Comment: As per above, you still do not need to use an IAM Role from Account B.

Comment: But we can use other AWS services within VPC by providing VPC Endpoint. I did this to access SNS also and that worked.But the same is not working for STS.

Comment: But then how will I get sts client in the code of Lambda Function. There I am getting sts client by passing Account B IAM Role ARN.

Comment: You do not need an IAM Role in Account B. As per my answer, the Bucket Policy on `Bucket-B` can refer to the IAM Role from `Account-A` that is being used by the Lambda function. The IAM Role in `Account-B` is not necessary. The Bucket Policy in your answer already refers to the Lambda role, which is all that is necessary. You do not need STS credentials.

Comment: yeah..got it..I removed STS code and IAM Role in Account B..and still got it working. But its still not working within VPC. I created STS VPC Endpoint as well. Is it mandatory to create NAT Gateway to make this working?

Comment: If an AWS Lambda function is _not_ connected to a VPC, then it is automatically connected to the Internet. If the function _is_ connected to a VPC, and it needs to access an AWS API endpoint, then it either needs the NAT Gateway (see above), or it can use a VPC Endpoint to get to the API endpoint without going through an Internet Gateway. Put simply, if you don't need the Lambda function to specifically access resources in the VPC, then do not configure it to use the VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that you may need to specify the region and region endpoint for the STS API. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-sts-regionalized-endpoints.html)

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts'
        region_name='eu-west-1',
        endpoint_url="https://sts.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")

    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::<Account-B-ID>:role/access-s3-bucket-from-lambda-in-another-acc-role",
    RoleSessionName="cross_acct_lambda"
    )
    print('acct_b: ',acct_b)
```