# AWS lambda function getting timed out - Task timed out

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm quite new to AWS Lambda. I created a function that reads JSON files stored in an S3 bucket. Picks up the 'memory_usage' value from each JSON file and adds them and publishes them to an SNS topic. This code runs completely fine when I'm executing it from my local machine using boto3 only but gets timed out when I deployed it in Lambda.

```py
import boto3
import json
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
sns = boto3.client('sns')

bucket = s3.Bucket("<s3-bucket-name>")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    total_mem = 0
    for file in bucket.objects.all():
     
        body = file.get()["Body"]
        print(body)
        data = json.load(body)
        memusage = data["memory_usage"]
        total_mem += int(memusage)

print(total_mem)

reportdt = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

msg="""
---------------------------------------------
Memory usage report for publish1 for {}
---------------------------------------------
Combined memory usage: {}
---------------------------------------------
""".format(reportdt,total_mem)

sub = "Memory usage report for publish1 for {}".format(reportdt)

response=sns.publish(
    TopicArn ="<sns-topic-arn>",
    Message = msg,
    Subject = sub
)

print(response)

print(msg)
print(sub)
```

What did I mess up? TIA

```sh
Function Logs
START RequestId: c3138409-eb32-4926-9cd5-1cc846ebe89c Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: c3138409-eb32-4926-9cd5-1cc846ebe89c
REPORT RequestId: c3138409-eb32-4926-9cd5-1cc846ebe89c  Duration: 3040.04 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 22 MB  
2021-08-14T16:46:48.820Z c3138409-eb32-4926-9cd5-1cc846ebe89c Task timed out after 3.04 seconds
```

Comment: Lambda configured to [run in VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) and [needs internet access](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)? PS your code indentation looks to be wrong.

Comment: @jarmod No it is not configured to run in VPC and does not require internet access through igw.

Comment: OK, assuming that it does indeed have access to the relevant AWS service endpoints, then you might want to simply increase the timeout (and possibly the configured RAM size) of the Lambda function.

Comment: Also worth noting that [Athena can analyze JSON](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-JSON.html) (and other) data in S3 so could also potentially be used to query and sum your JSON files' memory_usage values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you may want to check here.

1. Your Lambda should have a return:

For Python, it *typically* takes the format

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': response
}
```

and should be inserted at the end of the `lambda_handler` function. You should check out [this Python Lambda example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) to get an idea of what skeleton Lambda syntax looks like.

--

For Lambda troubleshooting in general, you should check out [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html). Using the logging library and then going over to CloudWatch logs is very helpful when you're troubleshooting Lambda functions in the cloud.

In addition, [AWS X-Ray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/aws-xray.html) is a more intensive service you can also use for tracking the movement of your function's execution, but in your use case that shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: Lack of IAM permissions would not typically cause timeouts. Requests would fail with an AccessDenied response almost immediately.

Comment: I was thinking of this issue I saw a while back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349986/lambda-times-out-while-accessing-s3-bucket-in-another-account-using-boto3

But that is probably not the likely problem and I'll remove it as a suggestion until further information is provided

Comment: @N.G.Perrin I have provided specific permission to the bucket in question in the IAM Lambda execution role. However, I'll try giving S3FullAccess to see if that helps.

Comment: which region is the bucket in and in which region are you executing the lambda?

Answer (score 0):

From the information available, your Lambda function does have internet access and can reach AWS service endpoints, but it's timing out when listing and reading S3 objects.

You should simply increase the timeout of the Lambda function, from its default of 3 seconds. You may also want to increase the configured RAM size because this will increase the performance of the Lambda function (both CPU and network bandwidth) which will cause it to process these S3 files more quickly.

Something else worth looking into longer term - it may be worth evaluating Athena in case it's more performant/cheaper than your current solution. Athena can analyze JSON (and other) data in S3 so could potentially be used to query and sum your JSON files' memory_usage values.